# How to see progress of .csv upload in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have a very large .csv file, and I'm loading it into mysql with the LOAD DATA INFILE command.  Because it takes so long, I'd like to see how far along the upload has progressed.

I've tried 2 methods so far-
First I simply did a SELECT COUNT(*) command to see how many rows had been inserted as the upload was in progress, but that always returns a count of 0.
Second, I tried SHOW PROCESSLIST and saw simply how long the query has been running.  sometimes the status says 'freeing data' or something to that effect.

Does anyone know a good way to track the progress of a LOAD DATA INFILE command?  Also, does anyone know how to track the insertion rate?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.stephenchu.com/2008/12/speed-up-your-mysql-data-load.html, you can use the  `SHOW INNODB STATUS`  IF your table is Innodb type, which you didn't happen to mention.

The  page I linked to also has some good  tuning suggestions to improve your overall performance with loading data in this manner.

Comment: `SHOW INNODB STATUS` should now become `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G;`, with the extra trailing `\G`, so that `grep` works

Answer (score 33):

On Linux you can print info about file descriptor (ls -l /proc//fd), and file position reader (cat /proc//fdinfo). So:

1. Find mysqld pid (in this example: **1234**):

   `$ ps -ef | grep mysqld`

   `mysql    1234     1  0 feb12 ?        00:00:55 /usr/sbin/mysqld`
2. Find file descriptor number of your loaded file (in this example: **45**):

   `$ sudo ls -l /proc/1234/fd`

   `lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Feb 13 10:56 45 -> /var/lib/mysql/db/Loaded_file.txt`
3. Print info about that file descriptor and check number of bytes already read (in this example: **494927872**):

   `$ cat /proc/1234/fdinfo/45`

   `pos:   494927872`

   `flags: 0100000`

You can compare this progress indicator (in bytes) to the actual file size being loaded.

Instead of step 1 and 2, you can also use 'lsof' command:

```
$ lsof /var/lib/mysql/db/Loaded_file.txt | grep mysql

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME

mysqld    1234 youknowwho    45r   REG  252,0   190312 5505353 /var/lib/mysql/db/Loaded_file.txt
```

Comment: This combined with the time the query had been running gave me an incredibly accurate ETA. Hugely useful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of approaches here...

1. `set session transaction isolation level read uncommitted`; Then count(*) will work
2. `select
       rows_read as 'Read',
       round((rows_read/{linecount})*100, 2) as 'Complete',
       round(time/60, 2) as 'Elapsed',
       round(time * 100 / round((rows_read/<line count>)*100, 2) / 60, 2) as 'ETA'
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
   where id = <id>;`