# LOAD DATA INFILE + progress tracking

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, innodb

I made a PHP console script that downloads big CSV file (> 2.5m rows) and insterts it to the database. I'm using `LOAD DATA INFILE` query here and it works perfectly, taking ~20 seconds to complete.

I'd like to track progress of this query. I've read about several approaches here, but I don't know how to run `LOAD DATA INFILE` query and then run progress tracking loop. The script waits until `LOAD DATA INFILE` is done.

My database is MySQL and the engine is InnoDB. I'm using Laravel framework.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748565/how-to-see-progress-of-csv-upload-in-mysql and http://dotmanila.com/blog/2013/04/check-rough-progress-of-your-csv-import-to-mysql/ and also this one http://derwiki.tumblr.com/post/24490758395/loading-half-a-billion-rows-into-mysql

Comment: @tzafar I checked all of them out before asking this question.

Comment: @RoboRobok Then it would be helpful to explain why it is not address your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can "split" the dump file with [pt-fifo-split](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-fifo-split.html) and print progress message after each chunk.

For example, in shell:

```
f=dump.sql
nlines=`cat $f | wc -l`
let chunk=$nlines/100

pt-fifo-split --lines $chunk $f
i=0
while [ -e /tmp/pt-fifo-split ] 
do 
    echo "$i% is done"
    mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/pt-fifo-split' INTO ..."
    let i=$i+1
done
```